# Adding to req.params object in middleware for error handling

Tags: node.js, express

Some context before my question:

1. I'm currently building a server in Node, Express, MongoDb + Mongoose
2. I'm using PassportJS for authentication

Every route I have is protected by a middleware confirming that the request is authenticated. On top of that I have different levels of permissioning (ie, is_regular_user, is_account_approved, is_team_admin, is_firm_admin) which I am also using middleware for.

In the event one of these middleware checks fails, I am redirecting to a generic 400 error handler. However, I would like to pass some info to that error handler so I can return a custom error message to the client (so I can tell them who to contact in my company for what error).

I'm thinking of appending a message (specifying which middleware check failed) to the req.params Express object, which the generic error handler can check and then use to print a custom error message. Does this approach make sense? If not, what would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be something like this

```
// handle
authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
 const error = doAuthLogic(req);
 if(error){
   res.send({ error: e});
   return;
 }
 next(req, res);
}
app.get('/api', authMiddleware, myController );
```

and in **doAuthLogic** you can pass all the required information

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So you recommend throwing an error in the middleware itself, instead of using a generic error handler. Out of curiosity - what would you say is the rationale behind this choice?

Comment: I think that doAuthLogic can return an Error or a boolean or an object, because this is an handled error. You might want to add in your server.js  a generic handler for generic error, something like app.use(function (err, req, res, next) { //return appropriate message to client }):